# REST API GET for a document does not work

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

given a document "file.docx" located in a library "documents". When I enter http://server.site/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeURL('/site/documents/file.docx'),
into the browser, I receive a correctly detailled xml view.
When I use the same URL for a REST call in a ShP 2013 Designer workflow as a GET method (the required dictionary with the accept header 'application/json;odata=verbose' has been created aforehand), it fires a http500 error.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Deepmala, it's a SpD2013 workflow, so I only can copy/paste like this:

Comment: Stage:1
 Log Initializing ... to the workflow history list
 Log creating vRequestHeader ... to the workflow history list
 Build {...} Dictionary (Output to Variable: vRequestHeader )
 Log Starting the call ... to the workflow history list
 Call http://.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeURL('/dev/restapi/docs1/TestDocTSG.docx')/listitemallfields. HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to Variable: vResponseContent |ResponseHeaders to responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: vResponseCode )
 Log vResponseCode = [%Variable: vResponse... to the workflow history list
Go...

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Comment: 2013 on premises

Comment: Shp2013 enterprise on premises to be precise